# Which pose/stretch is this?

Tags: stretching, yoga

The one on the bottom right - I often have upper back pain and it seemed interesting! 
[image: Stretch]

Comment: It is similar to gomukhasana...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm mainly familiar with this exercise with the other arm reaching up to reach the arm going down. My [stretching program with GMB](https://gmb.io/ff/) calls it "Shoulder Combined Motions". When I was a child, checking out yoga books, they called it the "Cow pose", but that's typically used to refer to a different pose, and instead you'll see it called "Cow Face pose", or *[Gomukhasana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gomukhasana)* (and technically also involves a particular leg positioning).

When we did it in martial arts or soccer warmups more like what you show in the image, it was simply described as "reach your arm over your head and down your back, and lightly push down on the elbow with your other hand while resisting with the stretching arm."

Comment: Thanks - your fitness program sounds interesting! Is it available online?

Comment: @Qasim: Sure. I added the link.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of the exact name, but many people just call it "tricep stretch"

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hSaqjF0dMMg) explains how to perform the stretch.

Comment: Thanks, any more info on the stretch - does one just hold the pose in the picture, or pull your right elbow with your left hand?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hSaqjF0dMMg, this video explains it pretty well

Comment: The video is really helpful, really did explain it quite well. I'd suggest adding it to your answer :)